# NSStream ends after locking phone

Tags: iphone, ios, locking, connection, nsstream

My online app runs on iPhone-3GS iOS 4.3, use NSStream to communicate with server.

When I minimize the app, lock phone, and relaunch my app the streams will end.

So my app loses connection to server.

Anyone knows how to keep the connection after locking phone? Is it a feature of iOS multitask?

Comment: Read the guide from the answer by SCC in the following SO Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481457/nsexception-kills-the-app-if-raised-in-background

Comment: You should actually clean up all ongoing connections when entering background and restart them while entering foreground. If you app is a VoIP app than do what DarkDust says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature of iOS. Networking connections of backgrounded apps are cut off. You need to request "VoIP" treatment: for this, you need to set the ["voip" value for the Info.plist key `UIBackgroundModes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) and then mark your socket as being a VoIP socket setting the [kCFStreamNetworkServiceType of your socket to kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketStreamRef/Reference/reference.html) using [CFReadStreamSetProperty](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/Reference/reference.html).

See also the [Apple iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf), section *Tips for Developing a VoIP App*.

Comment: @nminhtai: i'd just add that if your app isn't a VoIP app then you shouldn't do this if it's ment for app store.